# ios - Parse PFQueryTableViewController numberOfRowsInSection Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, tableview

I have A PFQueryTableViewController.

It is similar to how Instagram displays their feed.

Here is a picture of my storyboard:

[image]

I use the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}
```

So for each object, there is a section. In each of those sections their is four cells. This is so I resize certain cells dynamically, easily. (For example the cell that contains the object's text can resize dynamically depending on the amount of text).

**The problem is if I have less than four objects retrieved from parse, this code causes a crash:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 4;
    }
```

I added a exception breakpoint and it shows this method is responsible for causing the error:

```
- (PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.objects[indexPath.row];
}
```

It highlights this line specifically for causing the error:

```
return self.objects[indexPath.row];
```

So for some reason, if this method returns less than four objects, for example:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }
```

Then I get that error described above. Here is an image of my console:

[image]

My hypothesises is that whatever is returned in this method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Is used as the index to call this method:

```
[self.objects objectAtIndex:methodReturnValue];
```

Thats why if there is less than 4 objects and the `numberOfRowsInSection` asks for 4 cells per section and also calls the above method, then it's obvious it will through an error because its asking for an object at indexPath 4 when there is only 1 object.

I am not if that is the actual error, but it is the closest I have gotten.

Here is a resource I used for some of my code, because I am using sections in my `PFQueryTableViewController` : [Parse Sections Post](https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections) (Even though I ended up just accessing `[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];`)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right in your analysis!

[However, `PFQueryTableViewController` already implements `numberOfRowsInSection`, so there is no need for you to implement it too.](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUI/Classes/QueryTableViewController/PFQueryTableViewController.m#L293)

All you need to implement is the `queryForTable`, and the superclass will take care of the rest.